# How to format old disk after installing new boot disk?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, m.2

I just installed a [250 GB m.2 SSD](https://www.wd.com/en-ie/products/internal-ssd/wd-blue-ssd.html) as a Windows 10 boot drive on an Acer Aspire E15. The computer previously had Windows 10 installed on a 1 TB HDD.

This is what my current configuration looks like:

[image]

Disk 1 is the SSD boot drive running Windows 10. Currently, the EFI System Partition appears to be listed as a boot drive during restarts, which is a problem. How can I format Disk 0 (the old 1TB HDD) so that the drive contains a single partition with no strings attached?

I have tried the following DISKPART commands with no success (See errors below).

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
* Disk 0    Online          931 GB  1041 MB        *
  Disk 1    Online          232 GB      0 B        *

DISKPART> delete disk override

The disk you specified cannot be deleted.
Please select an empty missing disk to delete.

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
* Disk 0    Online          931 GB  1041 MB        *
  Disk 1    Online          232 GB      0 B        *

DISKPART> clean

Virtual Disk Service error:
Clean is not allowed on the disk containing the current boot,
system, pagefile, crashdump or hibernation volume.
```

Answer (score 0):

You still have partitions on the disk, delete these first then try `delete disk`

You also need to 'select' the disk, before trying to delete anything.

`list disk`

`select disk 1`

`list partition`

`select partition 1`

`delete partition`

.... and so on.